# Passing parameters into Windows command line script

Tags: windows, parameters, batch-file, cmd

I want to pass SampleText as a parameter into my Windows batch script

```
for %f in (SampleText*.sj) do find /i "SampleText_" %f >> temp.txt
```

I tried to replace SampleText with %1

```
for %f in (%1*.sj) do find /i "%1_" %f >> temp.txt
```

but this this throws the error: 1*sj) not expected at this time.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running this script inside a batch file, you need to double your percent sign for loop variable:

```
for %%f in (%1*.sj) do find /i "SampleText_" %%f >> temp.txt
```

Comment: @S.S. consider to use the accept button to accept Alexander solution